How to make the calculations on specific dynamic widget?
`In my code I make dynamic text widget and side have button with minimise icon.
My problem every time I press the button to make the calculations happening on different text than the one that is side by the icon .
How can I make them in the button that is same side from the text ?
This is the code that have to do with  with the buttons
for (int data in dynamicData)
                DynamicItemWidget(
                  data: data,
                  onDelete: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (data>1){
                        dynamicData.remove(data);
                        data = data -2;
                        dynamicData.add(data);
                      }
                      else {
                        dynamicData.remove(data);
                      }
                    });
                  },
                ),
              // Add button to dynamically add widgets
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    dynamicData.add(5);
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Add Colony'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
//

class DynamicItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int data;
  final VoidCallback onDelete;

  const Dyna`micItemWidget({required this.data, required this.onDelete});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(


      title: Text("$data"),
      trailing: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.minimize),
        onPressed: onDelete,
      ),
    );
  }
}



`

You might need keys to distinguish between same-typed widgets within an element.  See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html

Try storing index for each text data and on delete, remove the value at index instead of dynamicData.remove(data).
Something like  dynamicData.removeAt(index)
Essentially, your code is regenerating a new list every time you remove or add, which might not be what you want.
I do not follow your delete button logic but as far as I understood you want to delete the respective Text widget by hitting minimize Icon,generated after clicking add colony.
You can add more code for better resolution of the problem.
